# sphinx field block operator error

Tags: sphinx

I am creating a very complex `Sphinx .cnf` file on a very large `MySql` Table and in order to efficiently test it I have a test config I use on a smaller table. Once I get the behavior I expect/want I copy the new config content over to the working config. However the last time I did this and rotated the on site query gave me `query: “query error: invalid character '|' in field block operator”` even though the rotation was successful. I get this is somewhat of a vague question but are there any suggestions as to what to look for? My config is very large and complex and a line by line isn't practical. All I know is that:

- When I revert back to the older working config the site query works
- When I run the query on the test site with the test sphinx config it works
- When I replace the working config with the working test config I (all of a sudden) get that error.

Comment: I think to have any hope of diagnosing, would need more details. Only other suggestion is to save to two configs in a seperate files and compare them with a 'diff' program, maybe made some small change you didnt notice.

Comment: @barryhunter That is my next step yet there are big differences as well that are inentional. I thought perhaps the error itself pointed to some issue in the query itself vs the config since the index rotated "successfully" yet throws an error when the query is run.

Comment: @barryhunter The two indexes are far enough off where the differences won't tell me much. The bigger issue/clue though is that when I copy the test index over it fails on the same query that it doesn't fail on when querying the test index the same way. I thought perhaps that might be a clue as to narrow down what to look for.

Comment: No, doesnt really point to anything. Imagine trying to diagnose an issue with a car from a vague email, really need to see the actual car, to have a hope of diagnosing it.

Comment: @barryhunter Thanks Barry I will just slog through it then, they are massive indexe rulesets that no one but me would really care to bend their minds around. If I find out a good explanation of why the same index fails in one instance and not the other I'll update here.

Answer (score 0):

You query may like this:

```
@(column1|column2|column3) some search keyword
```

Just replace | to ,:

```
@(column1,column2,column3) some search keyword
```

And  equivalent to:

```
@(column1,column2,column3) some | search | keyword
```